# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal <script>...</script> tag not working within a string variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please look my code.

```
var id = 1;
var htmlText = '<div id="horizontalUserPopup"><ul id="tabs1" class="rtabs"></ul><div class="panel-container"><div id="view1"><script>viewMiniProfile("'+id+'",this);</script></div><div id="view2"></div><div id="view3" style="display:none;">Blah Blah Blah</div><div id="view4" style="display:none;">444444</div></div></div>';
$('#contents').html(htmlText);
```

Above code i am getting following error -

[image]

If i remove `</script>` its working fine. Please check and let me know.

**EDIT:**

Complete Code -

```
function modelInfo(id, username) {
                var pageUrl = $('#pageurl').val();
                $('#model-popup-box1 h3').addClass('newsfeed');
                var content_area = $('#model-popup-content1');
                content_area.html('Please wait...');
                $('#model-popup-box-title1').html('About ' + username);
                $('#model-popup-body1').show();

                content_area.html('<div id="horizontalUserPopup"><ul id="tabs1" class="rtabs"></ul><div class="panel-container"><div id="view1"><script>viewMiniProfile("'+id+'",this);</script></div><div id="view2"></div><div id="view3" style="display:none;">Blah Blah Blah</div><div id="view4" style="display:none;">444444</div></div></div>');

                var innerHtml = "<li><a href=\"#view1\" id='miniprofile-view1' onclick=\"viewMiniProfile('"+id+"',this)\">Mini-Profile</a></li>" +
                        "<li><a href=\"#view2\">Tokens</a></li>" +
                        "<li><a href=\"#view3\">Notes</a></li><li><a href=\"#view4\">PM Logs</a></li>";

                var ul = document.getElementById("tabs1");
                ul.innerHTML = innerHtml;


                $('#horizontalUserPopup').responsiveTabs({
                    rotate: false,
                    startCollapsed: 'accordion',
                    collapsible: 'accordion',
                    setHash: true,
                    disabled: [4, 5]
                });

            }
```

Comment: Can you post complete code.?

Comment: Check now my updated code. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm going to assume your quoted code is in a `script` tag, like this:

```
<script>
// ...stuff here...
$('#contents').html('<div id="horizontalUserPopup"><ul id="tabs1" class="rtabs"></ul><div class="panel-container"><div id="view1"><script>viewMiniProfile("'+id+'",this);</script></div><div id="view2"></div><div id="view3" style="display:none;">Blah Blah Blah</div><div id="view4" style="display:none;">444444</div></div></div>');
// ...stuff here...
</script>
```

If so, the problem is that the outer `script` tag is terminated in the middle of your string, because the HTML parser in the browser doesn't interpret JavaScript code, it just scans through it looking for `</script>` to figure out where the tag ends. So the code that gets handed to the JavaScript parser is

```
$('#contents').html('<div id="horizontalUserPopup"><ul id="tabs1" class="rtabs"></ul><div class="panel-container"><div id="view1"><script>viewMiniProfile("'+id+'",this);
```

...which does indeed have an unterminated string literal.

You can fix that by:

1. Putting your JavaScript code in a `.js` file and linking to it, or
2. Putting a backslash before the `/` in the ending script tag in your string:

   ```
   $('#contents').html('...<script>...<\/script>...');
   ```

   The `\` prevents the browser's parser from seeing the sequence `</script>`, and to so it doesn't think the script ended there. In a JavaScript string, however, `\/` is just `/`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape it using `\`, else it will be a part of the HTML.

```
var htmlText = '<div id="horizontalUserPopup"><ul id="tabs1" class="rtabs"></ul><div class="panel-container"><div id="view1"><script>viewMiniProfile("'+id+'",this);<\/script></div><div id="view2"></div><div id="view3" style="display:none;">Blah Blah Blah</div><div id="view4" style="display:none;">444444</div></div></div>';
$('#contents').html(htmlText);
```