# Regular expression to find HTML text script tag's content and src value

Tags: javascript, regex

```
let htmlTEXT = `<h1>page 1</h1>
<input type="text" spellcheck="false" data-ms-editor="true">
<script src="/static/test.js">
    console.log("hello");
    console.log("goodbye");
</script>`

// hopeful regex magic to produce the below
// -> /static/test.js
/* -> 
   console.log("hello");
   console.log("goodbye"); */
```

I have a string which contains HTML, and I would like two regular expressions to get

1. the script's src value
2. the script's content

Comment: Does this have to be done with regular expressions? It would be a lot more robust if you have the option to use javascript to create a new HTMLElement and use that to parse the htmlTEXT string.

Comment: Obligatory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 — Please pick [a better tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying this client-side, rather than regex, perhaps the easiest modern way would be to use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), and then use [`parseFromString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) on the string.

For nodeJS look into [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/).

If you see the following error:

> SyntaxError: `` literal not terminated before end of script

you'll need to escape the the closing `/` in the `</script>` element first. You'll see if you just add what you have to a JS file it will error out with:

[So change that to `<\/script>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30231195/1377002).

Then you can parse the string, and then pick out its `src` and its text content.

```js
const str = `<h1>page 1</h1>
<input type="text" spellcheck="false" data-ms-editor="true">
<script src="/static/test.js">
    console.log("hello");
    console.log("goodbye");
<\/script>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');

console.log(doc.querySelector('script').src);
console.log(doc.querySelector('script').textContent);
```

Comment: "However - and this action needs to be taken whatever process you use - you need to escape the the closing `/` in the `</script>` element first" — This is only true if the JS appears inside a `<script>` element and not in a standalone `.js` file.

Comment: The  DOMParser API is available in browsers, but the OP hasn't said they are running their JS in a browser (as opposed to, for example, Node.js).